# A confusion in the Lua5.4 documentaion

Tags: lua, documentation

> Unless stated otherwise, any overflow when manipulating integer values wrap around, according to the usual rules of two-complement arithmetic. (In other words, the actual result is the unique representable integer that is equal modulo 2<sup>n</sup> to the mathematical result, where n is the number of bits of the integer type.)

the above is a paragraph in the lua 5.4 manual and I couldn't understand what it actually says and I have just started learning this language.

Comment: read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow,  unless your integer calculations result in values greater than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 this shouldn bother you.

Comment: to resolve confusion like that simply google any keyword you don't know.